# Destructuring assignment in Typescript for global variables

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following statement:

I'm receiving an `object` from somewhere like the following in example:

```
paginationConfig = {
  currentPage: 1,
  pageSizes: [5, 10, 15],
  perPage: 20
};
```

My class:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  currentPage: number;
  pageSizes: number[];
  perPage: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    { this.currentPage, this.perPage, this.pageSizes } = paginationConfig; 
    // It prints undefined for all those variables and I receive the error:
    // TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

    // It works for local variables (as below), why not when I use **this**?
    const { currentPage, pageSizes, perPage } = paginationConfig;
  }
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is destructure the `object` like the examples in [**this**](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/destructuring.html) book.

I can get it work if I use **local** variables, but in my case I really want these as global. Isn't it possible/supported?

**PS:** I already tried to wrap everything in parenthesis, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Object.assign` from within your class:

```
Object.assign(this, paginationConfig);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It really works :) Can you explain why destructuring does not work for *global* variables?

Comment: +1 - Yeah, this seems like the current solution. I did some research, and using `Object.assign` was suggested in GitHub [issue #5326](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5326). The issue is still open, and the proposed TS solution was `constructor(public {name1, name2})`, but that hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks @JoshCrozier for link.